# How to pass where DateCreated > DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 10 DAY ); condition?

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I'm new to codeigniter and I want to select a user's details by passing many conditions. I passed some conditions like:

```
 $this->db->where ( 'userprofile.Disability', $Disability);
 $this->db->where('userprofile.LivingCity', $LivingCity);
```

Similarly, I want to pass this where condition:

```
where DateCreated > DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 10 DAY );//how to write in code igniter format?
```

How to write that ^ in code igniter format?

eg:

```
`$this->db->where('userprofile.DateCreated>', DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 10 DAY);`// how to write this?
```

How to write that ^?

I want to pass this condition to select the person who inserted the value before 10 days and my select table is:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('Userprofile');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write custom where condition in codeignitor.

> $where = "DateCreated > DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 10 DAY )";
>
> $this->db->where($where);

checkout CI's Active Record Class : https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html